# Draw an implicitly defined surface in 3D

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, 3d

I want to visualise the following set as a subset of `[0,\infty)^3`:

[image]

What's the most efficient way to do this? I am thinking of either `TikZ` or `psTricks`.

Comment: @Jubobs How did you insert the TeX output? I wanted to do it like this but didn't know how.

Comment: I simply generated the TeX output on my machine and took a screenshot.

Answer (score 7):

I think `pgfplots` can be used here, but you need to take an ad-hoc approach.

If I understand the problem correctly, the restriction of your set to `[0,m]^3` (where `m` is some nonnegative value) corresponds the union of the convex hulls of three triangles:

- `(0,0,0)`, `(0,m,m)`, `(m,m,m)`
- `(0,0,0)`, `(m,0,m)`, `(m,m,m)`
- `(0,0,0)`, `(m,m,0)`, `(m,m,m)`

My approach was to draw those three triangles separately with one `\addplot3` each, using the `patch` and `patch type=triangle` keys. To get nice colours, I change the `colormap` for each plot; there's probably a better way of doing that...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\begin{document}

\[
    \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}_+^3 :
    (x=y, z\leq x) \vee (y=z, x\leq y) \vee (x=z, y\leq z)\}
\]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\xmax{1}
    \begin{axis}[%
        xtick={0,\xmax},
        ytick={0,\xmax},
        ztick={0,\xmax},
        xlabel=x,
        ylabel=y,
        zlabel=z,
        view={125}{45},
    ]
    \addplot3[colormap/cold,opacity=.9,patch,patch type=triangle]
    coordinates {
        (0,0,0) (\xmax,\xmax,0) (\xmax,\xmax,\xmax) 
    };
    \addplot3[colormap/bone,,opacity=.9,patch,patch type=triangle,]
    coordinates {
        (0,0,0) (\xmax,0,\xmax) (\xmax,\xmax,\xmax)
    };
    \addplot3[colormap/earth,opacity=.9,patch,patch type=triangle]
    coordinates {
        (0,0,0) (0,\xmax,\xmax) (\xmax,\xmax,\xmax)
    };
    \node[coordinate,pin=above:{(\xmax,\xmax,\xmax)}]
        at (axis cs:1,1,1) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit**: A more elegant alternative in TikZ:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xmax{1}
\[
    \{
    (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}_+^3 :
    (y=z, x \leq y) \vee
    (x=y, z \leq x) \vee
    (z=x, y \leq z)
    \}
\]
\centering

\tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{125}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]


    \tikzset{
        axis/.style={->,black},
        framework/.style={dashed,black},
        triang/.style={opacity=.8,},
    }

    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\xmax*sqrt(3)}{54.7356}{45} % arcsin(sqrt(2/3)) = 54.7356
    \pgfmathsetmacro\endcoord{1.2*\xmax}

    % draw the origin and axes
    \draw (O) node[anchor=south]{$O$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- ({\endcoord},0,0) node[anchor=east]{$x$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,{\endcoord},0) node[anchor=west]{$y$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,{\endcoord}) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

    % 1. Draw \{(x,y,z) \in [0,\xmax]^3 : (y=z, x \leq y) \}
    \filldraw[
        draw=red,%
        fill=red!20,%
    ]          (O)
            -- (0,\xmax,\xmax)
            -- (\xmax,\xmax,\xmax)
            -- cycle;

    % 2. Draw \{(x,y,z) \in [0,\xmax]^3 : (x=y, z \leq x) \}
  \filldraw[
        triang,%
        draw=blue,%
        fill=blue!20,%
    ]          (O)
            -- (\xmax,\xmax,0)
            -- (\xmax,\xmax,\xmax)
            -- cycle;

    % 3. Draw \{(x,y,z) \in [0,\xmax]^3 : (z=x, y \leq z) \}
    \filldraw[
        triang,%        
        draw=green,%
        fill=green!20,%
    ]          (O)
            -- (\xmax,0,\xmax)
            -- (\xmax,\xmax,\xmax)
            -- cycle;

    % draw point M, its coordinates and dashed lines                            
    \draw[framework] (P) -- (Pyz);
    \draw[framework] (P) -- (Pxz);
    \draw[framework] (P) -- (Pxy);
    \draw[framework] (Px) -- (Pxy) -- (Py) -- (Pyz) -- (Pz) -- (Pxz) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```